# How do you prove $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee \neg q)$ is logically equivalent to $(p\to q) \wedge (q \to p)$?

Tags: logic

From my math after distributive property you get $(p \wedge q) \vee ( \neg p \wedge \neg q)$, not $(p\wedge q) \wedge (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$. How do you turn that $\vee$ into a $\wedge$?

Comment: $\lnot p \lor q$ is equivalent to $p \to q$. See [Material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)).

Comment: the primitive way is to look at all combinations of truth values of $p$ and $q$ and evaluate the truth value of both expressions. they must be the same for all combinations.

Comment: Isnt $(\neg p\lor q)\equiv p\to q$ and  $(\neg q\lor p)\equiv q\to p$ ?

Comment: it is true that $\neg p \vee q \equiv p \rightarrow q$. but you also need that $\phi \wedge \psi \equiv \phi' \wedge \psi'$ under the assumption that $\phi \equiv \phi'$ and $\psi \equiv \psi'$.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $(p\implies q)\iff (\lnot p\lor q)$ and $(q\implies p)\iff (\lnot q\lor p)$. Hence,
$$\color{red}{(\lnot p\lor q)}\land\color{blue}{(p\lor\lnot q)}\iff \color{red}{(p\implies q)}\land \color{blue}{(\lnot q\lor p)}\iff \color{red}{(p\implies q)}\land \color{blue}{(q\implies p)}$$